# Moving Multiple Rows to Columns with a Concate Situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, concatenation

I have probably what would be considered a simple question - I need to move multiple rows into a single row, based on concate of member IDs and date.

What I have is a table that may look like this:

```
Row   Member ID      Create Date    Answer
1     1234          20170101    20170101
2     1234          20170101    1
3     1234          20170201    20170201
4     7778          20180301    1
5     7781          20180201    2080201
6     7778          20180301    20180301
```

What I need is to match Member ID with the Create Date in a possible Concate situation, then move both answers for that member/create date into one row.

The end result would look like:

```
Row    Member ID    Create Date Answer     Answer 2
1      1234         20170101    20170101    1
2      1234         20170201    20170201    
3      7778         20180301    1      20180301
4      7781         20180201    2080201
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are a maximum of two answers, then you can do:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id)) as new_id,
       MemberID, Create Date, min(Answer) as Answer,
       (case when max(answer) <> min(Answer) then max(answer) end) as answer2
from t
group by MemberID, Create Date
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  Not usually just max of 2, but this will help when I do have only 2.

Comment: @user9539580 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  I would suggest that you accept one of the answers and ask *another* question if you have a more complex problem.  If you change this question, you will invalidate answers and that can draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG` and aggregate results in one column:

```
select  Member_ID ,Create_Date, STRING_AGG (Answer, ',')    
from table_1 group by Create_Date, Member_ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72775/3

Comment: Yes, but that isn't what the OP asked

Comment: We are only at 2014, but will keep this for later reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For any number of answers Column

```
Select
    Row_NUmber() over(order by (select 1)) as id,
    A.[Member ID],A.[Create Date]
    ,STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +  CAST([Answer] AS varchar)
          FROM Table1 T
          WHERE A.[Member ID]=T.[Member ID] and A.[Create Date]=T.[Create Date] 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as [Answer] 
         into #test
FROM Table1 A
Group by  A.[Member ID],A.[Create Date]
DECLARE @pivot varchar(8000)
DECLARE @select varchar(8000)
SELECT 
        @pivot=coalesce(@pivot+',','')+'[Answer'+cast(number+1 as varchar(10))+']'
FROM 
        master..spt_values where type='p' and 
        number<=(SELECT max(len(Answer)-len(replace(Answer,',',''))) FROM #test)

SELECT 
    @select='
        select p.*
        from (
        select 
            id, [Member ID],[Create Date],substring(Answer, start+2, endPos-Start-2) as token,
            ''Answer''+cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by start) as varchar(10)) as n
        from (
            select 
                id, [Member ID],[Create Date], Answer, n as start, charindex('','',Answer,n+2) endPos
                from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type=''p'') num
                cross join 
                (
                    select 
                        id,[Member ID],[Create Date], '','' + Answer +'','' as Answer 
                    from 
                        #test
                ) m
            where n < len(Answer)-1
            and substring(Answer,n+1,1) = '','') as Answer
        ) pvt
        Pivot ( max(token)for n in ('+@pivot+'))p order by id'

EXEC(@select)
```

Output:

```
id  Member ID   Create Date Answer1 Answer2
1   1234    20170101    20170101    1
2   1234    20170201    20170201    null
3   7778    20180301    1           20180301
4   7781    20180201    2080201     null
```

Live Demo

> http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8bc3689108b8cec2c95259182296f76